# Does Calvary Chapel assume everything is wrong in this world?

Tags: church-local

(I ask this question because my only exposure to Jesus has been through Calvary Chapels for many years.)

If you attend [Calvary Chapel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calvary_Chapel) (or ever listened to the radio station [K-WVE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KWVE-FM) broadcasted nationally or I guess world-wide now) there seems to be an undertone of something always having to be wrong in this life. People call in with testimonials about being drug addicts, ill, etc and it was Jesus that saved them (which is great!).

But it seems this is where this non-denomination starts to max out.

At the church I go to, I sincerely wonder if the pastor is happy at all in this life and he seems only focused on the next...

Is this the basis of catch as many people as possible (for Jesus) since we all hit hard times?

Is specific to this non-denomination or is it generic to other Christian "ways" ?

Comment: I'd hasten to point out that if we're *NOT* focused on the next life, this life can overshadow everything else

Comment: this is true....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your description, this sounds simply like the application of the Calvinistic doctrine of [Total Depravity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_depravity), which is typical of many congregationalist congregations.

Comment: very interesting article and does have many aspects of what I have come to know through CC.

Comment: Total Depravity, however, shouldn't be without recognition of God's common grace given to all mankind.  Short of that, it becomes something really sour and dour and mean.  God has given us so much, and we're undeserving of it.  The fact that we're undeserving is total depravity.  The fact that the economy is in a bad place is simply unfortunate.

Comment: @AffableGeek: so which doctrine would be more focused "in the middle" of this total depravity vs God's grace?

Comment: @David Morton: so which doctrine would be more focused "in the middle" of this total depravity vs God's grace?

Comment: @GregMcNulty Total Depravity simply says that is incapable saving himself on his own.  It is God's grace that enables man to be saved. There is thus no "middle ground" - they are completely complementary